# SelectableText widget not take changes from field textHeightBehavior

Tags: flutter, text-widget

I need to change my height behavior for bubble message of a chat.

regular **Text** widget works as expected: 
[image: TextWidgetExample]
 remove top height from the first line of a text, but **SelectableText** ignore that field: 
[image: SelectableTextExample]

```
textHeightBehavior: const TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false)
```

Mb someone know what the cause? Or this is a bug of Flutter?

Comment: try with. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectableText/selectionHeightStyle.html . This may help your issues .

Comment: @RahulKushwaha no one vallue from SelectableHeightStyle does any changes to the visual height (that spacing persist)

Comment: try other properties .

Comment: nothing worked, I try all of this before post that question